# Factory pattern, return a generic class and have an argument

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I have this implementation of Factory Pattern

```
public interface IFactory<T>
{
    T GetObject();
}

public class Factory<T> : IFactory<T> where T : new()
{
    public T GetObject()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

But I'd like than `GetObject` return an instance of a generic class `Repository<Customer>` (`Repository implement IRepository`) and the factory has an argument (ISession type)

The result should be :

```
IRepository<ICustomer> myRepo = new Factory<ICustomer>(session);
```

How can I do this ?

Thanks,

Comment: This is a pretty complex question, are you wanting to know how to construct the generic class using the specified constructor parameter? Or are you looking for a deeper insight on how to map and resolve a request for `IRepository<Customer>` to a `Factory<Customer>`?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky updated the question. The client now the interface

Comment: this sounds like the sort of thing most IOC/DI libraries would be very good at...

Answer (score 1):

Consider having a parameterless constructor instead, and some initialization function that takes the parameter. Other than not being able to pass a parameter through your factory, consider the case when you will want to deserialize your objects. They should be constructed and then the parameters should be filled one by one after that.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be so generic? Why not like this?

```
public interface IFactory<T>
{
    IRepository<T> Create(ISession session);
}

public class RepositoryFactory<T> : IFactory<T> where T : new()
{
    public IRepository<T> Create(ISession session)
    {
        return new IRepository<T>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you really need that level of generic but you can use generic fluent factory approach and have initialization function not from constructor instead.

```
  var CustomerGeneric = GenericFluentFactory<Customer, WebSession>
                        .Init(new Customer(), new WebSession())
                        .Create();


public static class GenericFluentFactory<T, U>
{
    public static IGenericFactory<T, U> Init(T entity, U session)
    {
        return new GenericFactory<T, U>(entity, session);
    }        
}

public class GenericFactory<T, U> : IGenericFactory<T, U>
{
    T entity;
    U session;

    public GenericFactory(T entity, U session)
    {
        this.entity = entity;
        this.session = session;
    }

    public T Create()
    {
        return this.entity;
    }
}
```